# Why isn't Matlab's Classification Learner the End All?

Tags: r, machine-learning, python, matlab, data-mining

After building some machine learning models in Python, R and Matlab, I found the latter's Classification Learner App to be immensely powerful. In the time it took me to build a **single** model in Python or R, I churned out **250** in Matlab.

Why don't auto-generated models features dominate when it comes to model creation? Also, why doesn't Matlab dominate as a result?

Comment: Were the 250 Matlab models more accurate in prediction than the single R or Python model?

Comment: In addition, are you familiar with caret or scikt-lrn ?

Comment: So what? Producing absolutely random predictions would be even faster. Ease of use, or speed are not the primary criteria for judging statistical software.

Comment: @aginensky, I hadn't come across caret. Thanks for sharing this one. But yes, I see your points that easily produced models may not offer better results than a single, well optimized model. It's something I hadn't considered. Thank you!

Comment: I'm hearing the question as "what are the technical, production, or business weaknesses in this approach+solution in light of your limited (welcome to the human race) experience and exposure, that can cause it not to be the holy-grail (or silver-bullet or whatever).  That doesn't sound so opinion based, and I think that stats folks could speak to it.  They already are in the comments.  Licensing fees.  Alternative packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because of the high fees of MATLAB distributions, while R and Python are free.

Comment: I edited the question after you provided this answer, which was 'Why doesn't Matlab dominate the machine learning industry?' It was originally deemed an opinion-based question.